# BaseController does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to define a base controller in ASP.NET MVC project -

```
public abstract class BaseController:Controller
{
    protected readonly ExpressDbContext DbContext;
     string _baseUrl;

    public BaseController(ExpressDbContext context)
    {
        _baseUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"].ToString();
        DbContext = context;
    }

    protected new ViewResult View()
    {
        this.ViewBag.BaseUrl = _baseUrl;
        return base.View();
    }       
}
```

Then inheriting it from other controller-

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{        
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I saw some examples to declare a base controller like this. But this time I am getting exception-

```
BaseController does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments
```

I'm also binding a DbContext in Ninject -

```
kernel.Bind<ExpressMvc.DB.ExpressDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

Any thing I missed or out of knowledge?

Comment: On your `BaseController`, add this line of code `public BaseController(){}` and that't it :)

Comment: Check it out may be you are missing ninject.web.mvc package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are inheriting from BaseController in which you have explicitly defined a constructor with one argument, a default parameterless constructor is not created for BaseController and HomeController does not have a constructor defined so a parameterless constructor is created and is is expecting a constructor with a same signature in the base class.

You can either create a parameterless constructor in the base class or define explicitely that  this constructor `public BaseController(ExpressDbContext context)` should be called like this

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{        
    public HomeController():base(ExpressDbContext _ObjectToBePassedToTheBaseConstructor)
    {
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding an empty constructor to the abstract base, which may be not what you want if you actually need `ExpressDbContext`, you should add a constructor to your implementation instead.

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public HomeController(ExpressDbContext context)
        : base(context)
    {

    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the empty constructor. Otherwise c# compiler does not find the overloads hence it throws an error. It finds only the BaseController(ExpressDbContext context) overloads.

```
public BaseController()
    {

    }
```

If this is missing, you are implicitly telling the compiler to use the default constructor without parameters. Because no such constructor exists in the base class it is giving you this error.